# Wicket - FileUploadField, Ajax and Preview

Tags: wicket, asyncfileupload

Im using Wicket 1.5 and I need to build a component with a FileUploadField to load an image.

I need an Ajax behaviour to make a preview of image after selected it (without submiting the entire form).

Searching on Google, I found this Event that match when I select the file:

```
AjaxEventBehavior choose = new AjaxEventBehavior("onChange"){
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Override
      protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
      }
};
```

What I need is the stream of image to put in a little panel that required:

```
byte[] imgBytes
```

And obviously I need the same stream to fill a PropertyModel for DB storing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either `AjaxFormSubmitBehavior` (will submit the entire form on the given event) or `AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior` (will submit only the one form component. I'm not sure whether the latter works with file uploads, just give it a try. You can always use the former.

In the model of your FileUploadField you will find a (list of) FileUpload - look at the methods you get, there are input streams and other things available so you can do pretty much anything with the data.